# Excel - import API data not importing all rows, how to add a "rows" parameter? Beginner question

Tags: excel, powerquery

First time posting. And a non "coder" type user.  so I appreciate the patience.

I have been given an API key to access data from a web service we use. It has an address with "Https://.....key=....."

The goal is to import these records into Excel and have it update daily. It should be about ~1300 records.

I have successfully gotten some data into Excel using "Get Web Data" and entering the provided URL with the API key.

The issue is I only seem to get 25 rows or records of data.

Looking at some documentation from the vendor who provides the info they say:
"By default, our APIs return data in JSON format. Other supported formats are plain XML and Property List (plist)."
Then they show a list under
"Global Query Parameters" then lists things such as:

- fields
- Locale
- rows
- sort
- etc

Possibly the issue may be that it could only be returning records where the a field called "status" is "active" and possibly this should be specified as all or any.

Another possiblity may be that there needs to be a Row parameter with "9999" or something.

I don't have any coding experience here so I need the beginner steps.

This is the power query editor info.

[image: editor]

when I expand the results it show only 25 records.

[image: expanded1]

[image: expanded2]

Comment: Not knowing what you're trying to access, or their documentation: What do you get when you try out the API in [Postman](https://www.postman.com/)? Keep in mind that some APIs paginate etc., but 25 seems low to me. PS. If you don't know how to use Postman, there are some good articles out there. The reason you want to test it in Postman first if you're running into issues is that if Postman works and what you're trying in Power Query doesn't, the issue is with Power Query, not the API.

Comment: In your second snip it says "numResults | 1381" this is telling you there are 1,381 rows available. You need to go-through the API documentation as those "Global Query Parameters" are going to be essential. For example `rows` - what does this do? I suspect it will be the number of rows to return. There maybe another one called `skip` which is usually skip the x amount of rows and return the next. This is how pagination works in API. So add `?rows=100` or `&rows=100` to your API call as a start to see if you get 100 rows back...

Comment: Thank you both. I will check out Postman later today and also look at adding a "rows" parameter, to the end of API.

Comment: Thank you.  Postman allowed me to test what I needed to do quickly and get to the right result!